# Problems importing Json file into mongodb using python

Tags: python, mongodb, import, pymongo

Could anyone help me out with the following problem? I have been struggling with this problem for days... 
I have to import json files into mongodb using python. 
I tried both insert_many and insert_one but I get errors with the following code:

```
import json
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient


mng_client = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
mng_db = mng_client['mydatabase1']
collection_credits = mng_db['credits']

with open('credits.json') as f:
    file_data = json.load(f)
    collection_credits.insert_many(file_data)

client.close()
```

error message:
document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON...

and with:

```
import json
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient


mng_client = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
mng_db = mng_client['mydatabase1']
collection_credits = mng_db['credits']

with open('credits.json') as f:
    file_data = json.load(f)
    collection_credits.insert_one(file_data)

client.close()
```

error:
 BSON document too large (191071260 bytes)

Comment: What error did you get? Please provide [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I edited the post

Answer (score 0):

[insert_many](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=insert_many#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_many) requires an iterable (e.g. a list), [insert_one](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=insert_one#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_one) takes a single record.

Use insert_many if your data looks like this:

```
[ {
  "a": "1"
} ]
```

Use insert_one if your data looks like this:

```
{
  "a": "1"
}
```

As for the other error, mongodb documents have 16MB file size limit. You will need to pre-process the file to reduce the document size.

Answer (score 0):

Also look at `[mongoimport][1]` which can import JSON data directly.